# Test position inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I think I have a easy problem but I just cannot solve it.

```
<table>
<tr><th><img src='http://i.imgur.com/znH0q5A.jpg'></img></th>
<th style='position: relative; top:0;'><h3>Test</h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 
justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 
sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ay1pts5/

But I want it to look like this:

[image: How it should look like]

I want to put any text inside the  tags detached from the image on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the contents in another div

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

th {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

h3 {
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img src='http://i.imgur.com/znH0q5A.jpg'></th>
    <th>
      <div>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et 
justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata 
sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to set the  `margin` for `h3`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
th {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h3 {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><img src='http://i.imgur.com/znH0q5A.jpg'></th>
    <th style='position: relative; top:0;'>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not using a table for this simple work, instead you can `float` the image to the left and add a touch of css:

```html
<div>
<img style='float:left;margin-right: 10px;' src='http://i.imgur.com/znH0q5A.jpg'>
<h3>Test</h3><p style='text-align: center;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```